# WCF: How to publish a type which contains itself one to many times

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, soap

I'm trying to publish a SOAP service which contains an type which references itself one or more times. For example:

[image]

In the screenshot above, notice that ItemGroup can contain one to many other ItemGroups. I've tried the following:

```
public class ItemGroup : List<ItemGroup>
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
}
```

However, then I run the application, I get the following error:

> Type 'ItemGroup' is a recursive collection data contract which is not supported

It's possible to add a List to the ItemGroup, but the application consuming this service has requested that I don't do that.

EDIT:

I've looked at an alternative service which has implemented as above, and the WSDL looks like this:

```
<xs:element name="ItemGroup">
<xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Type" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:element name="Name" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" ref="ItemGroup" />
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

Comment: Couldn't it have a `List<ItemGroup>` as a property instead?

Comment: Yes, that was my original implementation, but the consuming application wants the format above

Comment: Use collection in your data contract class.

Answer (score 0):

you're using the wrong class

```
public class ItemGroup : List<ItemGroup>
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
}
```

class above isn't suitable because is a circular reference you can't inherit from a class that needs the same class you're implementing to be already defined.

I have reviewed the soap code and you need 2 classes one to define `ItemGroup` and other to define an object containing an `ItemGroup` List like this:

```
public class ItemGroup 
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
}

public class ItemGroups:List<ItemGroup> 
{

}
```